# send email with mandrill from angular ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, mandrill

Cannot send email using the mandrill api. I have added the controller to my markup, but when the send button is clicked nothing happens. I am following an example from the ionic forums and believe I am missing something. So to be specific about what i need is: I would like to know how to send an email from my ionic app prefilled with submitted form data. obviously for testing I have not added ng-model to store the submitted data. Below is my code, please take a look. thanks

shop.html view code

```
<ion-view view-title="Shop" ng-controller="OrderFormController">
  <ion-content>

    <div class="card">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="service in services">
            {{service.name}}
                <button class="button button-outline button-small button-stable" ng-click="toggleActive(service)" ng-class="{active:service.active}">
                    {{service.price | currency}}
                </button>
        </ion-item>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="service in services | filter:true">
            {{service.name}}<br>{{service.price | currency}}
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            Total: {{total() | currency}}
            <button href="#" class="button button-outline button-small button-stable">
                    Checkout
            </button>
        </ion-item>
    </div>

    <form novalidate> 
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" ng-model="email">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone" ng-model="phone">
            </label>-->
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="address" name="address" ng-model="address">
            </label>
        </div>
    </form>

    <button class="button button-full button-stable" ng-controller="sentMailCntrl" ng-click="sendMail({
        toEmail: 'email@gmail.com',
        subject: 'New Order',
        mailBody: {{totalItems()}}
        })">
        Send Order
    </button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

OrderFormController

```
  myApp.controller('OrderFormController', function($scope) {

$scope.services = [
    {
        name: 'Espresso',
        price: 27,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Americano',
        price: 36,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Macchiato',
        price: 57,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Cappuccino',
        price: 42,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Mocha',
        price: 55,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Latte',
        price: 39,
        active:false
    },{
        name: 'Chai Latte',
        price: 50,
        active:false
    }
];

$scope.toggleActive = function(s){
    s.active = !s.active;
};

$scope.total = function(){

    var total = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.services, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            total+= s.price;
        }
    });

    return total;
};

$scope.totalItems = function(){

    var totalItems = "";

    angular.forEach($scope.services, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            totalItems+= s.name+" $"+s.price+".00 ";
        }
    });

    return totalItems;
  };
});
```

sentMailCntrl

```
var myApp = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);

myApp.controller('sentMailCntrl',function($scope, $http){
  $scope.sendMail = function(a){
    console.log(a.toEmail);
    var mailJSON ={
        "key": " ",
        "message": {
          "html": ""+a.mailBody,
          "text": ""+a.mailBody,
          "subject": ""+a.subject,
          "from_email": "noreply@fooddelivery.com",
          "from_name": "New Order",
          "to": [
            {
              "email": ""+a.toEmail,
              "name": "New Order",
              "type": "to"
            }
          ],
          "important": false,
          "track_opens": null,
          "track_clicks": null,
          "auto_text": null,
          "auto_html": null,
          "inline_css": null,
          "url_strip_qs": null,
          "preserve_recipients": null,
          "view_content_link": null,
          "tracking_domain": null,
          "signing_domain": null,
          "return_path_domain": null
        },
        "async": false,
        "ip_pool": "Main Pool"
    };
    var apiURL = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json";
    $http.post(apiURL, mailJSON).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('successful email send.');
        $scope.form={};
        console.log('successful email send.');
        console.log('status: ' + status);
        console.log('data: ' + data);
        console.log('headers: ' + headers);
        console.log('config: ' + config);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error sending email.');
        console.log('status: ' + status);
      });
  }
})
```

here is the console log when send email button is clicked

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toEmail' of undefined
at l.$scope.sendMail (app.js:6)
at ib.functionCall (ionic.bundle.min.js:229)
at ionic.bundle.min.js:386
at l.$get.l.$eval (ionic.bundle.min.js:156)
at l.$get.l.$apply (ionic.bundle.min.js:157)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.min.js:386)
at HTMLButtonElement.c (ionic.bundle.min.js:63)
at n (ionic.bundle.min.js:22)
at t (ionic.bundle.min.js:22)
at HTMLDocument.r (ionic.bundle.min.js:22)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing a parameter to your sendMail function.

The sendMail function requires you send an object looking like this:

```
{
  toEmail: 'emailaddress',
  subject: 'subject',
  mailBody: 'body of the email'
}
```

In your HTML make your call like this:

```
 <button class="button button-outline button-stable" ng-click="sendMail({
      toEmail: 'emailaddress',
      subject: 'subject',
      mailBody: 'body of the email'
    })">
```

Set the toEmail property to a valid email address.  If that works, then you can build out your app to use the email address that is entered in a form or however you plan on getting the email address.  You will need to set the subject and mailBody properties appropriately also.

Comment: OK well that successfully posted to mandrill api log but the email was nor sent out to the toEmail. Does it have something to do with "from_email" value? not sure what to put here because it is being sent from my app.. any ideas.. by the way thank you for your time...

Comment: Can you see what the send error was in the Mandrill logs?

Comment: I just received the email so it does work, just very slow....it looks as if it doesn't matter the from_email value.. My thinking is a verified domain might speed things up but until then i was just going to make an email up like for instance ..   order@appName.com

Comment: Good deal!  Sounds like you are on the right path now.

Comment: I guess since I'm at it any idea how to post a function result to the body string?example 
            mailBody: {{totalItems()}}

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Show the result of totalItems() in the view or send as a parameter value to mandrill?  Shoot me more details and I can help.

Comment: I have a checkout view which shows the result of totalItems(). That is working fine but when i try to submit that value to mandrill as a body parameter the email is sent but the body is empty.. basically what im trying to do is email the value of totalItems() and the values of 3 input forms (address, name, phonenumber) to mandrill to be posted.. i can get all this working in a view no problem.. using the data as parameters in the email is for me coming up short... again i really apprieciate the help...

Comment: Can you post your view code and your controller code? or update the current question with your current progress?

Comment: Did you combine your two controllers?  The totalItem() function would have to be in your sendMail controller to access it.  I'm not seeing the code where you are having the problem.

Comment: The totalItem() function is in the OrderFormController because i use that to populate the list for the checkout view. Do you think i should combine the two controllers or add the function to the sentMailCntrl. If I add the totalItem() function to the sentMailCntrl. how will it access the services array?

Comment: Ok, here's how I would do this but it's not in the scope of the question.  I would create a service that is responsible for sending emails to mandrill.  Make it generic so you can use it to send all kinds of emails.  I would then inject the service into the controllers where you need to send emails.  That way you can keep your controllers free of all your email send code.  Hope this points you in the right direction.  Angular is awesome once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Ok let me see what I can come up with. I already have achieved my goal for today with the original question. Thanks for all your help. Angular is pretty cool and thanks for going above and beyond. This will for sure help other people aswell..